# Can't connect to mySQL server from wsl

Tags: mysql, node.js, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a mySQL server setup on my Windows machine, i also have WSL installed so i can use all the goodies of linux on my Windows machine. I have an assignment to make a JS api with express with a connection to a database, so i run my mySQL server everything is running correctly , but when i start the JS api using `node index.js` from WSL and try to connect to the database, it throws an sql error

```
Server running on port 8080 , http://localhost:8080
/mnt/c/Users/ngkil/Documents/VSCode/WebDevAssignment2022/Backend/index.js:43
                if (err) { throw err; }
                           ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 3306,
  fatal: true
}

Node.js v18.1.0
```

if i run the same command `node index.js` from CMD the api works fine

```
Server running on port 8080 , http://localhost:8080
Connected to database
```

I do not understand what is going wrong between my mySQL server and WSL, the only interaction that exists between the two is that i try to connect to localhost from WSL, is it a unix problem???

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is not working, because WSL2 is running with a virtual network (vNIC) that is created by the Windows Virtual Machine Platform (a subset of Hyper-V). Inside WSL2, localhost is the address of the vNIC.

The simplest solution would be to get an ip address of your windows and connect to the database with this address instead of localhost.

Unfortunately the IP will change every time you run your linux. WSL stores your windows host IP in `/etc/resolv.conf` file. So you can modify `/etc/hosts` to map `winhost` to the host IP dynamically. To achieve this add the following lines at the end of `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export winhost=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{ print $2 }')
if [ ! -n "$(grep -P "[[:space:]]winhost" /etc/hosts)" ]; then
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "$winhost" "winhost" | sudo tee -a "/etc/hosts"
fi
```

then run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now instead of `localhost` use `winhost`. Please let me know if this has helped you

Comment: Wow , that is an answer way to detailed and way to useful , all i wanted was to be able to run my api from wsl, which from your answer i just put in my actual ip address instead of localhost and it worked. BUT i will definently try what you said cause it might be useful in the future if i need the localhost to work. A++ answer

Comment: just tried what you said. Yep deffinetly works , thank you very much. Now to connect i type `const connection = mysql.createConnection({ host: "winhost")};` and port user password and it works perfectly from wsl